# Is it possible to write divided multi lines in xml file for TextView's text property in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a TexTView in a activity showing multiline text in it.

In the xml file of it, I use the following syntax and it works. It displays 3 lines in TextView as expected

```
 android:text="xxxxxxx\nyyyyyy\nzzzzzz"
```

But I want to convert this information into multi line something like this to increase readibility. Because my lines are too long beyond the screen limits to see all at once in the xml file.

android:text="xxxxxxxxx\n
                     yyyyyyyyyy\n
                     zzzzzzzzzz"

When I use this syntax, the preciding blank part of each line becames the part of my text. So the textview appearance gets weird.

Is there a way to use multi divided texts in xml files as shown above?

Thank you?

Comment: Can you please provide an image of what you expect it to look like on screen and what you're getting right now?

Comment: you have to consider the size of the smartphone, display size and text size

Comment: No, I am not asking about the result at targeted device. I am just asking that, can I split strings in xml file? For example can I say android:text="hello at line 1 and world" at line 2.  In android Studio IDE we can do it. It allows us to split lines as we need to increase readibility